# Are multiple calls to the same method in the same statement optimized by the compiler?

Tags: java, android, optimization, java-8, compiler-optimization

Let's say I do something like this in Java 8 (Android specifically)

```
String name = someObject.getName() != null ? someObject.getName() : "null";
```

and the method `getName()` might have a lot of calls to other methods to resolve the name. Also suppose I'm calling this code quite often.

Would it be better, performance wise, to do something like this instead?

```
String name = someObject.getName();
name = name != null ? name : "null";
```

Comment: Chances are that the method _may_ return different results upon different calls, so this probably won't be optimized by the compiler.

Comment: You should use `String name = String.valueOf(someObject.getName());`. Starting with Java 9, there is a variant usable for all object types, `String name = Objects.requireNonNullElse( someObject.getName(), "null");`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like an optimization possible, called [CSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination); a `JVM` AFAIK does that (but not sure about Android).

But this highly depends on what `getName` does, if it allocates internally other objects and does some other things. Unfortunately I can't even tell how *to prove* me wrong or right here (might need to investigate); honestly I have a habit of doing this myself. For example:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i){

}
```

I try to always extract the `int size = list.size()` before the loop; even if this in my understanding is subject to `scalar replacement` optimization.

Comment: CSE will apply after all individual invocations have been inlined. Then, the optimizer is able to see whether the code is side effect free and boils down to the same operation each time. Regarding `list.size()` within a loop, it may get optimized the same way as repeated invocations of the same method, however, if the loop body contains operations which stop the optimizer, e.g. actions affecting inter-thread visibility, it’d require a provable purely local list instance to still have that optimization. Otherwise, it may end up in code re-reading the `size` field each time.

Comment: @Holger so effectively taking this two statements into a single variable would turn to be a good thing, right?

Comment: You should always avoid code duplication, that’s already for clarity. With an expression like `someObject.getName() != null ? someObject.getName() : "null"`, it is not obvious to the reader that `someObject.getName()` truly evaluates to the same result each time (though it’s obvious that the author *assumes* that), this does not only depend on the implementation of the `getName()` method, but also on the nature of the `someObject` variable, which might be a mutable shared variable. But consider [these alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52495606/#comment91935865_52495606)…

Comment: @Holger ha! funny thing: I've only learned about this today on an interview, should have remembered. excellent point!

Answer (score 0):

The second version is calling `getName` one time, while the first, in case is not null, it's calling that 2 times... so if it is very heavy, the second version is better.

As Arnaud said, you have to consider if the value can change between the two calls: in this case you will get a performance boost, but a risk to get an "old" value.